How to implement voice activity detection and stop Twilio voice bot on customer interruption?
I am building a voice bot using Twilio and Django. I have set up an outbound call with media streaming, which is working fine. However, I want to implement voice activity detection so that if the customer interrupts while the voice bot is speaking, the bot stops speaking immediately.
I am looking for guidance on how to achieve this using Twilio's Media Streams feature
I have set up media streaming for the Twilio outbound call using the  verb in the TwiML response.
This is my view:
class StartOutboundCallingView(APIView):
    
    client = Client(sid, token)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        from_ = request.data.get("from")
        to = request.data.get("to")

        if "from" not in request.data or "to" not in request.data:
            return Response(
                {"Required Field": "from and to are required fields"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        resp = VoiceResponse()

        call = self.client.calls.create(
            twiml=generate_twiml(),
            to=to,
            from_=from_,
        )
        return Response({"call_id": call.sid}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

this is how I am generating the twiml
def generate_twiml():
    return f'''
          <Response>
              <Connect>
                <Stream url="{url}"/>
              </Connect>
          </Response>
          '''

this is my websocket consumer:
class TwilioWS(WebsocketConsumer):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.groq_ai = None
        self.call_id = None
        self.stream_id = None
        self.transcriber = None
        self.tts = None
        self.thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    
    def connect(self):
        self.transcriber: DeepgramSTT = DeepgramSTT(self)
        self.transcriber.start_transcription()
        asyncio.run(self.init_groq())
        return super().connect()
    
    async def init_groq(self) -> None:
        self.groq_ai: GroqAI = GroqAI(self)
        self.groq_ai.initialize()

    def disconnect(self) -> None:
        self.transcriber.disconnect()

    def receive(self, text_data: str) -> None:
        """
        Handle incoming WebSocket message.

        Args:
            text_data (str): Base64 encoded audio stream.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        if not text_data:
            self.transcriber.disconnect()
            return

        data: dict = json.loads(text_data)
        event: str = data.get('event')

        if event == "start":
            self.streamSid: str = data['start']['streamSid']
            self.call_id: str = data['start']['callSid']

        if event == "media":
            self.handle_transcription(
                base64.b64decode(data["media"]["payload"]),
                self.call_id,
            )

        if event == "stop":
            self.transcriber.disconnect()

    def handle_transcription(self, chunk: bytes, call_id: str) -> None:
       
        """Handle transcription of a chunk of audio.
        Args:
            chunk (bytes): The audio chunk to transcribe.
            call_id (str): The ID of the call.
        """

        self.thread_pool.submit(
            self.transcriber.transcribe, chunk, call_id
        )
    
    // return response audio to twilio
    def handle_transcribed_audio(self, audio_data):
        # start_time = time.time()
        encoded_audio = base64.b64encode(audio_data).decode('UTF-8')
        self.send(json.dumps({
            'streamSid': self.streamSid,
            'event': 'media',
            'media': {
                'payload': encoded_audio,
            },
        }))



You can send a clear event to twilio to interrupt audio output immediately. You will have to use some kind of VAD to determine when speech is started and then send this request to stop twilio.
await websocket.send_json({
    "streamSid": stream_sid,
    "event": "clear"
})

